# PDF embed in Sharepoint

Tags: pdf

I'm trying to display PDF in sharepoint aspx webpage.Using this code inside in aspx page `<object><embed src="http://example/example.pdf" height="600" width="600"
 type=""></embed></object>`

Once i save the page on preview apear grey color for the size of 600x600. I'm not using webpart > content editor  because i don't have the html editor button unable and is best for me to work directly in the code.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you want to use would be something like this:

```
<object data='url/to/file.pdf' type='application/pdf' width='600' height='600'>
    <p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.</p>
</object>
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately is displayed in same way, just the grey area and i don't know what can be the reason. If i insert wrong path of the PDF it's says that the pdf couldn't be loaded. But if is the right path only the grey color is displayed.

Comment: Sounds like the mime type needs to be added. Check these links out for some help with that.

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Add-new-MIME-type-open-PDF-f6c57c32

http://forumaspnet.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/pdf-mime-type-support-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: can you please guide me to install this mime type script?...it will be good to try maybe it will gonna fix my issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Please use this approach for only allowing PDF, in Powershell

```
$webapp = Get-SPWebApplication <your webapp url>
$webapp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Add("application/pdf")
$webapp.Update()
```

So you don't have to allow all file types by setting file handeling to permissive

Comment: Note: If copy/pasting this take care not to use the "Smart Quotes" around the mimetype.

Answer (score 0):

Finally manage to fix the issue.

**Central Administration** > **Manage web applications**  > click on `http://yyy/` then **General Settings** > scroll down to  **Browser File Handling** and select **Permissive**

This is not very recommended but i think is best if the mime type doesn't do the thing.
However thanks for your time #iOnline247

Regards

Comment: Try my powershell above, should work and let's you only enable rendering of PDF:s

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache after trying the mimetype approach?

Comment: yes i've cleared the browser cache and was same. Now problem is solved with the above approach.